# Does anyone know of a way to view all compiler warnings for a VB.NET project?

Tags: vb.net, limit, compiler-warnings, max, vbc

VB.NET has this rather annoying limitation which caps compiler warnings reported at 100.

```
vbc : warning BC42206: Maximum number of warnings has been exceeded.
```

This makes things rather frustrating when trying to size up the amount of effort that would be required to comply with VB.NET best practices, such as enabling Option Strict.

Is there any way where this limitation could either be removed, adjusted, or could warnings be gathered by some other means (such as through a 3rd party code-analysis tool)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of VB11, in VS2012, `vbc` no longer has a maximum error limit when called from the command line.

There's probably a better link for this now, but [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2012/03/29/talk-what-s-new-in-vb11-vs11-beta.aspx#10288992) will do until I find one.

UPDATE: [new link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2012/02/28/visual-basic-11-beta-available-for-download.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

The official answer is apparently "No." From [Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=170749): "While this issue does exist, the Visual Basic Compiler Team has decided to leave the hard limit to the reported errors because it helps with performance."

Answer (score 0):

You should read [Configuring Warnings in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y20cc1z%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [How to: Enable or Disable Compiler Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzzzth4%28VS.80%29.aspx)

For example, you can to the compiler options (under the project build properties) the following line

```
warnaserror:42206
```

this should (I haven't tried it myself...) disable your 100 errors limit.

On another note, 100 warnings is a **very large number**. You should probably go over your code, check and fix the reasons to those warnings.

Comment: Please note that the goal of this question is to size up the number of warnings so that they can be fixed.  However, I do not know if my total warning count is 101 or 101,000.  

While these articles talk about how to enable or disable specific warnings, they do not address the warning cap, which applies to all warnings.  For the record, I do have all warnings enabled.

I did try the compiler options above, but unfortunately without success.

Comment: Haven't found a better solution. sry.

Comment: I have looked for this without success. When you make some major changes to a large project, it can be  simpler to fix the errors based on error type rather than the first 104 errors VS desides to display. You can use a search instead, but it doesn't work as well as clicking the next error.

Comment: you can try using something like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper), it does code analysis and can identify most of the errors before you compile

Comment: But it does dislike a lot of VB6isms if you have upgraded code.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with SQL projects I've been working on; the limit is 200 warnings.  Then as I fix them, new ones merge in so the number never goes down!

I found that if you look in the "Build" output in the "Output" tab you can see everything.  In my case I have thousands.  Just select all and copy/paste it into a text editor.

Comment: Not so with vbc, I'm afraid. It stops reporting warnings anywhere.