# Only Shows Error List For One vb File

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm kind of new to Visual Studio.  I've built a few simple programs in it, but now I'm in the process of rewriting a huge system I wrote in VBA.  What is frustrating me is the Error List in VS is only listing errors for one .vb File in my project, lets call that *VBFile1*. Now, when I work on another vb File, *VBFile2*, which is in the same project as VBFile1 no red squiggles or errors are listed for VBFile2.  I don't understand how this could happen.  This is what I've tried/checked:

1. Filter is set to 'Current Project' and I played around with the other Filter settings but no change.
2. Checked the Text Editor under Options and according to the research that I've already done it is fine.  Plus, I have never changed any of these settings anyway.
3. Closed and re-opened Visual Studio.
4. Closed all open files in the Project and still displays the same error list
5. Close all files except the VBFile2 but still shows the same error list of VBFile1.

I have Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.  I feel like this should be an easy fix...I just am really confused what's going on.

Hope this makes sense!

**UPDATE: Excluded from project, VBFile1 and finally errors are listed for VBFile2...why would this be?**

Comment: Are the other files open in Visual Studio?

Comment: @Tim refer to the edits that I just added.  Thanks.

Comment: There is a maximum number of errors per project that are visible at one time, if you exceed that it will not put the squiggles or show any additional errors.

Comment: Does one of those errors look like this?  `110 Maximum number of errors has been exceeded.`

Comment: @nickles80 I thought the same. The limit is 100 or 300 by default? I'm using C# and C++, maybe VB has some extra behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it has been fixed in Visual Studio 2012, but there is a [Connect Request for Visual Studio 2010](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/613412/provide-configurable-maximum-error-messages-limit-for-vb-net-compiler) with a resolution of won't fix because of performance issues. The effect your are seeing is because you have exceeded the maximum number of errors for that project (*what I am used to seeing is 102 as the threshold*), it will not show you anymore till you fix the ones that it has already shown you.

---

According to this [MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2012/02/28/visual-basic-11-beta-available-for-download.aspx), which I found through this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799272/does-anyone-know-of-a-way-to-view-all-compiler-warnings-for-a-vb-net-project) the limitation is still there for the IDE but has been removed for the command line compiler.

From above MSDN Link:

> Limitless (Command-line) Errors!
>
> This is actually a good thing, let me explain.  For performance reasons, the Visual Basic IDE maxes out at 101 errors (with error #102 being “Maximum number of errors exceeded.”)  This can make it difficult to estimate the amount of work remaining in certain situations, particularly in upgrade scenarios.  We have removed this limit from the command-line compiler in this release, though it still there in the IDE.  What this means is if you want to know exactly how many errors there are for a project, just invoke the compiler through msbuild.exe or vbc.exe and you’ll get your answer.